# Map String to Class Function in C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, pointer-to-member

I am writing a cocos2dx scene in C++. I am looking to create a set of string directions based on button presses that will be carried out when I update the scene. The issue is that I need to correlate these strings to methods of the class that can be overridden by subclasses to customize behavior based on button press. I am struggling to create a map between string and pointers to scene class methods.

Here is the applicable code

In Scene.h

```
std::map<std::string, void (Scene::*)()> correlateDirections;
```

In Scene.cpp

```
correlateDirections["c"] = &this->c

void Scene::c() {
    std::cout << "c" << std::endl;
}
```

XCode is giving me the error "Cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function."

When I try to make the pointer to the method constant, it still gives the same error.

In Scene.h

```
std::map<std::string, void const (Scene::*)()> correlateDirections;
```

Comment: Use `&Scene::c` to get address of member function

Comment: that works but how do i call the method in the update function?
correlateDirections[string]();  ?
It is saying the returned type is not a function or functionpointer

Comment: Get your function pointer and call it in this way: `(instance.*funcPointer)(args)`. And if You want use `this` as instance: `(this->*funcPointer)(args)`. The return type of `correlateDirections[string]` is an iterator. fetch it's internal data: `(this->*(*correlateDirections[string]))()`

Comment: thatll work, thank you kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's a pointer to member function, it's not self-contained and to call it you need and object of class Scene. See example below:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Scene
{
public:
    void runMe() { std::cout << "runMe" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, void (Scene::*)()> sfMap;
    Scene scene;
    sfMap["runMe"] = &Scene::runMe;

    // call via reference to object
    (scene.*sfMap["runMe"])();

    // call via pointer to object
    Scene* p = &scene;
    (p->*sfMap["runMe"])();    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the map is a class member